# How can I add space before my unit vectors?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vector

This is how I'm currently typesetting vectors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ih}{\mathbf{i}}
\newcommand{\jh}{\mathbf{j}}
\newcommand{\kh}{\mathbf{k}}

\begin{document}

$1/z \ih + \jh - y/z^2 \kh$

\end{document}
```

This gives me:

[image]

I think the unit vectors are too close to the expressions they follow. But if I place a `\,` in the definitions of the commands, extra spacing will also be added before the **j**-component here, which would look odd. What is the best way to add more spacing, preferably by changing the definitions of my unit vectors?

Comment: Check out the `\xspace` package. It may solve your problem.

Comment: @Ruben I don't think it will. From what I hear, `xspace` is for inserting spaces *after* macros, not before. (It peeks at the next token, not the previous one.)

Comment: Totally right, I realised that too now. Maybe try parentheses: `$(1/z)\ih + \jh - (y/z^2) \kh$`. It's really not an answer to your question, but I think it helps to make the expression look clearer with less work.

Comment: Why not just `$1/z\, \ih + \jh - y/z^2\, \kh$`?

Comment: @Zarko, because the author of the OP wants to automate this.

Comment: Try `\newcommand\ih{\mkern1.5mu\mathbf i}` and the like.

Comment: @Bernard As I mentioned in the question, simply adding spacing doesn't work because it also adds space before unit vectors without a component (**j** in this example), which looks bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a similar situation as for the differential symbol in integrals:

```
\documentclass{article}

% avoid code duplication
\newcommand{\unitvector}[1]{%
  \mathop{}\!\mathbf{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\ih}{\unitvector{i}}
\newcommand{\jh}{\unitvector{j}}
\newcommand{\kh}{\unitvector{k}}

\begin{document}

$1/z \ih + \jh - y/z^2 \kh$

$(a+b)\ih + (a+b)\jh$

\end{document}
```

[image]